# How can I get a POST value from a checkbox that appeared on a form after an AJAX query?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**index.php** has several fields, one of which is a dropdown named **item_A**. If a user selects a certain value in **item_A**, AJAX will cause a checkbox that is checked to appear on the form in **index.php**. The name of the checkbox is **check_A**.

However, when reading the values from the POST of **index.php**, the value from the checkbox is not present. How can I get the value of such a checkbox?

Here's the AJAX code between the HEAD tags of **index.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#item_A').blur(function(){
       $.post("process_A.php", {
        bookid: $('#bookid').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#usernameResult').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('usernameResult', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's the line from **process_A.php** which reveals the checkbox on **index.php**:

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_A\" checked> I would like Option A.";
```

And here's the area from **index.php**, between the FORM tags, where the checkbox appears:

```
<span id="usernameResult" style="color:green;"></span>
```

Comment: add value='something' attribute to checkbox and you can read it like other input elements in ajax call

Comment: Could you please post the contents of `finishAjax()` function? `$('#usernameResult').html(data);` works fine for me with the checkbox checked.

Comment: Yes - here is finishAjax(). I should have included it in my original post...my apologies.
`function finishAjax(id, response) {   $('#'+id).html(unescape(response)); 
$('#'+id).fadeIn();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the DOM code, but essentially if the element is added to the DOM (via PHP or AJAX) within the  tag and is syntactically valid then it will appear in the POST headers at time of submission. You could manually add a checkbox using dev tools in your browser of choice and the value would still post as the server has no prior knowledge of the page DOM submitting the request. The server is trusting that the browser is sending relevant information that is valid. If you post the DOM (Document Object Model - raw source HTML of the page after it is loaded and all values are added) then I might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

If elements are added to DOM dynamically after the initial page load, they work just the same. With a checkbox there are two things to keep in mind:

- Checkbox has to be inserted between  and
- Checkbox value is only sent if it is checked

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is .find()

jQUery can only grab what is available when the DOM (browser) loads. Seeing as you're pulling in a check box by AJAX, you're going to have to get the container for which you dropped the check box into

ex.

```
$('.container').find('.inner-box input[type="checkbox"]').val()
```

After this I'd add the value to a hidden field if it's still not passing. Although I'm unclear as to whether you're submitting the data and then the field is being populated or the checkbox is being entered and then you're submitting the form

Comment: Thank you - I still can't get this to work. The way I've been testing this is: the page loads; a dropdown is selected which causes the checkbox to appear on the form (this is working); and then the user submits the form. The problem is that the checkbox is not appearing in the POST. Since my last activity on this site, I've added a textbox with the value "hello" to process_A.php, and this is now also appearing on index.php along with the checkbox, but neither value is showing in the POST. All that being said, how would I implement your original suggestion?